# How can I obtain few of vc runtime dll's to include in my installer?

Tags: dll, vcredist

I've tried for many hours to find the solution for my problem and couln't find it even here.

So I have that application.exe that I am writing the Wix Toolset installer for it. Unfortunately I have no access to the source code but I hope I can do my task without it.

The problem is that it runs correctly with vc_redist.x64 installed on the end user's machine, but not without it.

What I've tried:

1. I was trying to run it without those runtimes and got into ["couldn't find vcruntime140.dll error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pjB8.png)

So  I pasted it in the app's folder and tried to move on with dll's and the next error occured as shown in picture:

[the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wrpX.jpg)

2. I've read those runtimes after installation go into eg. "C://Windows/System32"
   so I tried to go to that location and

`dir > before.txt`

and

`dir > after.txt`

after installing the vc++ runtime.

and copy pasted the files that occured only after the installation.

3. I tried to use gumpbin.exe from Visual Studio that gave given output:

[found some dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itq4k.png)

and the Dependency Walker gave me kind of  similar output.

Dependency Walker output the same libs as direct ones, but also gave imo about hundreds of indirect ones. So I thought copy/pasting all of them is a really hard job without software to help.

4. I was also thinking about forcing vc_redist.x64.exe to extract files to folder given by me so I could use them for my purpose and the only parameter that looked fine was /layout but it only copied the whole .exe to another folder. Didn't extract it.

My questions is:
is there an easy way of obtaining the vc_redist.x64 libraries so I could author only the needed ones in my installer?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

My goal is to secure newbie end users from being unable to run the application when they accidentally uninstall the VC runtime, therefore having vc_redist.exe as prerequisite in bootstrapper is unfortunetely not the case

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your fast answer. I edited my post. If I understand Microsoft docs, they say there are some .exe files with runtimes but I'm imteredted in standalone .dll files. Is it possible to somehow extract them or force .exe files to install them in a directory specified for me? Best regards.